# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cookie'

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

So, I've got a page where i set a cookie with js-cookie script and following code. js.cookie-2.1 is loaded right before that script.

```
 Cookies.set('dir', '1');
```

No JS errors there. When i try to get the cookie value on a different page, it looks like cookie script is not loading. Using following code

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var cookie = $.cookie('dir');
       if (cookie > 1) { 
          $(".thereiscookie").show(); 
          } else { 
          $(".testcookie").show(); 
          }
 });
```

And i'm getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cookie' of undefined". js-cookie script is also loaded right before the above code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: looks like jquery isn't loading on that page where you are trying to get back your cookie, or your jquery is in noConflict mode, try jQuery.cookie('dir');

Comment: Tried that. no good. And if jquery wasn't loading at all, i assume I'd get error a little earlier at "jQuery(document).ready(function(){" part

Answer (score -1):

JS Cookie moved away from jquery dependency a long time ago, infact the jquery version is no longer maintained. The version you have is of the newer kind. To set and get cookies, you would now use:

```
 Cookies.set('dir', '1');
 Cookies.get('dir');  //values is 1
```

There is no need to use jquery, its a standalone library.